# How to show data from two tables in a view/Blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel project with two tables.

1. `Property: id`, etc
2. `PropertyImage: id, property_id` (foreign key with property), multi-images for each property.

I want to show all the fields from Property as well all the images from the PropertyImages table which has the foreign key of property id.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you able to show what you've tried so far and also what issue you are having specifically (if any)?

Comment: Hello. Welcome. When you post questions, please include code that you have tried.

Comment: hi i have attached the code in Answer 3 please check this out and help me

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Property Model you have to define the relationship

```
class Property extends Model {
  ......
  protected $with = ['property_images'];

  public function propertyImages(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\PropertyImage');
  }
}
```

refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: class Property extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['propertyimages'];
    protected $table = 'property';
    protected $primaryKey ='id';
    public $timestamps = true;

Comment: class Property extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['propertyimages'];
    protected $table = 'property';
    protected $primaryKey ='id';
    public $timestamps = true;  

public function propertyImages(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\propertyImages');
        }
  
}


class propertyImages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'propertyimages';
    protected $primaryKey ='id';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function property(){
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Models\Property');
    }
}

Comment: $property = Property::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(6)->get()->with('propertyImages');   

this is my code. whats wrong here?

Comment: Check the data array in controller there will be an extra field `property_images`

Comment: you dont need to call `with` inside controller because of you define it in model

Comment: but the image dont shows i did like u said, how to call the image on view blade

Comment: what print_r($property) returns in controller?

Comment: this returns the property details, at the same time i have to return the image also but image is on onther table

Comment: instead of `$this->hasMany('App\Models\propertyImages')`  `App\PropertyImage` will be enough

Answer (score 0):

You need to create relation in Model like that

```
 public function Property()
       {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Models\','property_id');
       }
```

**In Controller send**

```
 public function index()
        {   
            $Propertyimage=Model::all();
            return view('return_in_your_view',compact('Propertyimage'));
         }
```

** In Your return_in_your_view.blade.php **

```
@foreach($Propertyimage->Property as  $property)

{{$property->property }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance. i got this error

Comment: please sure it you have made relation in model correctly

Comment: Your `hasMany` does not look correct. That isn't a name for a model class.

Answer (score 0):

[property table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4T9f.png)

[property image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cec9G.png)

[property model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3kRB.png)

[property image model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqcls.png)

[property controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUdIt.png)

i have included my code, since now i can view only the details from property details, now i have to view the image also